# skimage.transform.resize is slower than scipy.misc.imresize

Tags: python, scipy, image-resizing, scikit-image

I am training a neural network, while training I came across errors in a data preparation section. where this line:

```
img = np.double(scipy.misc.imresize(img, [height, width, channels], interp='bilinear', mode = 'RGB'))
```

and this line:

```
img2 = np.double(scipy.misc.imresize(img2, [height, width], interp='bilinear'))
```

showed errors, as **scipy.misc.imresize** is deprecated in newer versions of scipy. What I did is I used **skimage.transform.resize** instead of **scipy.misc.imresize**, that's what is recommended, as:

```
img = np.double(resize(img, (height, width, channels)))
```

and

```
img2 = np.double(resize(img2, (height, width)))
```

It worked.
But the problem is the data reading process has become very slow as compared to the **scipy.misc.imresize**. I had tested it before on old version of **scipy.misc.imresize**.
Any help in this regard would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I am training the model on Google Colab.

Comment: How much slower is it? Maybe it doing a higher order interpolation (cubic maybe)?

Comment: @Trilarion It takes around two hours in the reading process. With the scipy it takes around ten minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy-paste the source of imresize:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/misc/pilutil.py#L513

Comment: Didn't get it, sir @ev-br. Should I copy/paste this file's code in a  cell of my jupyter notebook before the execution of the mentioned code's cell?

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I did paste it in a cell before the code cell.